# JQuery Validation - Validate is Not a Function Error

Tags: jquery, validation

I've been working on this file locally and it has been working fine with no noticeable problems or error messages. However, as soon as I upload it to a server and try to run it I get the following error from Firebug in Firefox:

```
$("#DN0").validate is not a function
invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {  (line 80)
```

Here is the page with the script: http://admin204.earthcare.com/FMLA-test/jquery-validation/dn0_errorTooltip2.html

I found a similar post [JQuery validation plugin: $(“#”).validate() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073688/jquery-validation-plugin-validate-is-not-a-function)

This post prompted me to use the w3c validator on my html to make sure it was error free. I also believe that the JQuery and Validation plugin scripts are going to the right place and are in the right order.

I can't seem to figure this one out, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you are getting an error 403 when accessing http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js

You are probably not allowed to link directly to their repository, I would suggest storing the script on the server instead.

Comment: Wow, that was exactly it. Linked to it on the server and it works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: I will also note that the same error will occur if you forget to load the jquery.validate.js file :-). And the same fix happens if you do load it. It is assumed to be loaded by jquery.dataTables.editable.js and will fail with the "validate is not a function" error.. I spent a few hours on this because I assumed it was some type of jquery library mismatch. Thank you.